# C# how i can know the error code in kivy?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Simplekivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="salam")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Simplekivy().run()
```

this is what i get 
"
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Simplekivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="aleykum salam")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Simplekivy().run()
```

This code works; your installation/dependencies must be at fault. 
Please give us more to see what may be the issue.

Comment: salam , thanks for answer me ^^ , but which detail that you want to see ?

Comment: the output in your ide will have an error code which will point to what is missing